# How do you tell eclipse to update Jetty code in real time as you edit your code

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

While I am using Tomcat in eclipse, and have my web application running through eclipse, any changes to Java classes or JSP pages appear to get pushed straight into tomcat without having to do a restart of tomcat or the application.

Is there a way to configure Jetty under eclipse so that it works the same way? So far all I can seem to do is make code changes, and then manually restart jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Configure jetty.xml to use the ContextDeployer, which enable "hot-deployments". This may already be configured by default. Essentially, Jetty scans the contexts folder at a pre-determined interval. If it detects the WAR file or war directory has changed, then it reloads the context automatically.

In the example below, the ${jetty.home}/contexts folder is configured to look for context XML files that tell Jetty which Web applications to monitor. The scanInterval is set to 5 milliseconds, which means Jetty checks for changes every 5 milliseconds. You will find this configuration inside jetty.xml:

```
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Configure the context deployer                              -->
<!-- A context deployer will deploy contexts described in        -->
<!-- configuration files discovered in a directory.              -->
<!-- The configuration directory can be scanned for hot          -->
<!-- deployments at the configured scanInterval.                 -->
<!--                                                             -->
<!-- This deployer is configured to deploy contexts configured   -->
<!-- in the $JETTY_HOME/contexts directory                       -->
<!--                                                             -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.ContextDeployer">
      <!-- the ContextHandlerCollection to modify once a webapp is added or removed (Allows Hot Deployment) -->
      <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>

      <!-- the directory which will contain your context.xml files -->
      <Set name="configurationDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/contexts</Set>

      <!-- the interval in milliseconds to periodically scan the configurationDir -->
      <Set name="scanInterval">5</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

You'll also need to create a WebAppContext entry. Place this in a file called test.xml, and place that file inside the /contexts directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/test</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/test</Set>
</Configure>
```

Note that `<Set name="war">` refers to an actual folder, *not the WAR file.* This folder should contain the root of your application, such as your /WEB-INF folder and all other files.

If you want JSP and other pages to be recognized instantly, you'll need to configure the web application in the webapps folder to run from the exploded WAR, not the WAR file itself.  Afterwards, you'll need to point your Eclipse to this location so that you would essentially be modifying and compiling the files directly from the webapps/test folder.

In summary, you weren't clear which version of Jetty you're running. However, while Jetty configuration can vary significantly from version to version, this should get you started. See the [Jetty Website](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Walkthrough+jetty.xml) or the [Webtide website](https://www.webtide.com/) for more documentation on Jetty configuration and troubleshooting.

Once everything is configured correctly, you can modify and compile the code directly from that folder, without needing to restart Jetty.

The only exceptions to that rule are for cases where web.xml is modified. If you modify web.xml, you'll most likely need to restart Jetty.

As a final word of caution, make sure you don't deploy any WAR files named test.war inside your webapps folder, unless you've first disabled the exploding of WAR files. You may end up overwriting your code!

If you need additional guidance, you may find this [Jetty Documentation on ContextDeployers](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ContextDeployer) helpful, as well as [Deploying a Webapp to Jetty](http://www.enavigo.com/2008/08/29/deploying-a-web-application-to-jetty/). Good luck!